# Facing issues with CiviCRM installation on Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, installation, civicrm-home, menu

I manage to install CiviCRM on Drupal 7 ( had to do it manually ) and ran installation program successfully.

However, I am facing following issues :

1) civiCRM option is not  visible on top menu
 After investigating found recommended solution is to deselect/select civicrm module in Drupal. However, the checkbox seems to be disabled and not allowing to deselect (?).  I even cleared all cache in Drupal but that did not fix the issue.

2)  civicrm_membership table missing in MySQL database, I see other tables though.

Would be great if someone can let me know how to fix these...

Thanks

Explanation :

Steps followed for installation:

1) Downloaded and installed Drupal 7.57

2) Downloaded tar file civicrm-4.6.35 for Drupal

3) Tried to install civicrm using "install new module" section in Drupal.
Tried using both option, using URL as well as tar file upload, but was
not successful. 
  Surprisingly did not return any error message or warning...just did not work.
( I checked sites/all/modules folder under Drupal folder )

4)  I had to do manual installation by copying contents of tar file  under /sites/all/modules directory, as per some suggestion on the net.

civicrm folder appeared under /sites/all/modules

5) Ran the civiCRM installation script successfully 
( script /sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php )

6) The CiviCRM option did not appear at the top menu.

7) Looked for some solutions on google,  most suggested that I should disable and enable again the CiviCRM module on Modules section in Drupal

8)  I just cannot deselect ( turn off) civiCRM option !
The option is checked and seems disabled.

Comment: What do you mean by 'had to do it manually'?  Sounds like there may have been some issues early in your installation process.

Comment: Agree with Aidan - you need to put in the step-by-step process of how you installed if you are hoping others can give useful pointers

Comment: Are any of the other CiviCRM modules enabled (e.g. CiviCRM Theme)? If so you may need to disable them before you disable the main CiviCRM module.